# How should i send reset passwords emails with firebase and express?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I built a social website and I'm trying to add reset password feature.
I didn't use the Firebase SDK (everything is handled using express)
Is there an easy way to add reset password features that not involving the SDK? 
I saw that it is possible to create the reset link in the server and then send it to the client but I didn't understand how I can do it.

Also, is that a bad practice to use the SDK only for one feature?

Comment: I wouldn't generally consider it a bad practice to not use a single feature from the sdk alone.
Do you use the express backend to get data from firebase and then provide it via rest api? In my opion that's more of a problem. Maybe a firebase expert can elaborate? (I know they are around here :))

Comment: Exactly. I'm using express to get data from firebase and then sending it via res API.
Why that would be a problem?

Comment: Because it's an additional step that doesn't really need to be. I can't figure an obvious reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make a page with a textbox to make the user update the password. I think there is no problem using the Firebase SDK only for one feature

Comment: The user can update the password when he is logged in 
But I want to handle a case when the user forgot his password and I need to send him an email with JWT token

Comment: but you want to send him the password in the JWT? I didn't understand. If you want to send him an email, just look for a library to send an email and then in the body write a link with the parameters you want

Comment: They're supposed to be an easy way with firebase SDK 
I just wondered if it possible to implement that way through the backed to avoid the use of nodemailer or any other send an email library